# Radio Mics Usable in Israel?

Tags: radiomics, international

I have a client who is about filming part of a documentaru in Israel and is looking to purchase 2 radio mics for the shoot. They will be purchased in Germany. It looks as though Sennheiser may not be usable there. Can anybody suggest what radio mics are usable please? Have never had to think about this issue and information seems to be hard to come by. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Best ask in the JWsoundgroup.net forum. They'll know.